# How to resolve Cors Policy error in restify when using restify-cors-middleware

Tags: node.js, cors, restify

I am using restify-cors-middleware in my restify server 
But still facing cors error I have tried it by using like this below

```
const restifyCORS = require('restify-cors-middleware');
const cors = restifyCORS({
        origins: ['*']
    });
app.pre(cors.preflight);
app.use(cors.actual);
```

Showing Error like this

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/login' from origin
>   'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header
>   field access-control-allow-credentials is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Anyone could you please help me on this ..It swallow my whole day.Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove whatever part of your frontend code is trying to add an access-control-allow-credentials request header to the request. access-control-allow-credentials is a response header, not a request header.

Comment: In front end I have analyzed and removed the access-control-allow-credentials header that was mentioned in one part..But still facing the same Issue